# Excel Some Text still visible

Tags: vba, excel, button

I use 1 button and 1 spinButton. These buttons are for navigating true my workbook.

The button is for navigating to my table of contents the spinbutton up is the next page, spinbutton down is for the previous page. But I have one problem. I have 3 sheets. On the second sheet is a textbox with some text in it. I click on the spinbutton for the next page, sheet 3 activate but I see the textbox of sheet 2. So I think that excel need to refresh or something?

My code take some objects in the sheet to the next sheet. When I just click on the sheets under I haven't got that problem. It's only when I click on my spinbutton that some objects are in the next sheet but they supposed to stay on the previous sheet. When I see them I can't click on them. It's like a refresh fault of excel.

I hope you guys can help me with my problem. Here can you see my code for navigating between the sheets with a spinbutton and a commandbutton

```
    Sub volgendePagina()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lSheets As Long
Dim lSheet As Long
Dim lMove As Long
Dim lNext As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
lSheets = wb.Sheets.Count
lSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
lMove = 1

With wb
    For lMove = 1 To lSheets - 1
        lNext = lSheet + lMove
        If lNext > lSheets Then
            lMove = 0
            lNext = 1
            lSheet = 1
        End If

        If .Sheets(lNext).Visible = True Then

            .Sheets(lNext).Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lMove

End With

End Sub


Sub vorigePagina()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lSheets As Long
Dim lSheet As Long
Dim lMove As Long
Dim lNext As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
lSheets = wb.Sheets.Count
lSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
lMove = 1

With wb
    For lMove = 1 To lSheets - 1
        lNext = lSheet - lMove
        If lNext < 1 Then
            lMove = 0
            lNext = lSheets
            lSheet = lSheets
        End If

        If .Sheets(lNext).Visible = True Then
            .Sheets(lNext).Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lMove

End With

End Sub

Public Sub inhoudsTafel()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: so basically all it does is activating the next sheet / previous sheet or the first sheet... does this error occur when selecting another sheet namually?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

```
Sub volgendePagina()
  Dim i as Long
  i = ActiveSheet.Index
  do
    i = i Mod ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count +1
  loop until ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lNext).Activate
End Sub

Sub vorigePagina()
  Dim i as Long
  i = ActiveSheet.Index
  do
    i = i - 1
    if i < 1 the i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
  loop until ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lNext).Activate
End Sub

Public Sub inhoudsTafel()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
  'note: ThisWorkbook = the workbook which contains this code
  'ActiveWorkbook = well... the currently active workbook :)
End Sub
```